# Как передать ссылку в таблицу sqlite3?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite3

У меня есть код на Python:

```
def ChangeLink(message):
        db = ConnectDb.db('users.db')
        db.execute('UPDATE groups SET links={} WHERE id={}'.format(message.text,message.from_user.id))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'<b><i>Вы успешно поменяли силку на канал</i></b>{}'.format(config.horay),parse_mode='HTML')
```

но при попытке обновления ячейки *links* с пустой на ссылку у меня выдаётся ошибка:

> File "C:\Users\38093\Desktop\Pythons Scripts\PythonScript2021\ProjectOne\ConnectDb.py", line 8, in execute
> sql.execute(text)
> sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"

Помогите разобраться?

Comment: попробуйте `links={}` заменить на `links="{}"`

Comment: @5c0rp Реально помогло! Я считаю этот комментарий заслуживает большего! Сделайте его ответом, чтобы я мог вам поставить галочку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не формируйте вручную запрос SQL если данные в нем передаются из вне (это чревато sql-инъекциями), лучше используйте биндинг.

Попробуйте:

```
db.execute('UPDATE groups SET links=? WHERE id=?', [message.text, message.from_user.id])
```